# How to display MongoDB data in html page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I'm working on a project where I need to display the user data into the HTML web-page. For that, I have already created the POST and GET methods for API. I don't know how do I display the data on the webpage. 
PS: I'm not allowed to use frameworks like angular or react. I have to do it with MEN stack.

POST method:

```
router.post('/adduserdata', (req, res) => {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                error: err
            });
        }
        else {
            const user = new userdata({
                name: req.body.name,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: hash,
                mobile_no: req.body.mobile_no,
                data_of_birth: req.body.data_of_birth
            })
            try {
                user.save()
                res.json({
                    message: "User Created.."
                });
            }
            catch (err) {
                res.send('Error');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

GET method:

```
router.get('/getuserdata', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await userdata.find().select("name email mobile_no data_of_birth")
        res.json(user)
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.send('Error ', err)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll basically need to do some DOM handling and Ajax requests.

In pure JS:

```
const htmlElement = document.getElementById("YourElement");
const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
         const data = req.response;
         console.log(data) // Shows the returning data, that will probably be a JSON OBJECT.
         htmlElement.inneText = data.name;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "/getuserdata");
xhttp.send();
```

Code BREAKDOWN:

`htmlElement`: creates a constant variable that contains a HTML element with the provided ID.
`req`: creates a HTTP request client.
The rest of the code is all about this two variables. The HTTP client called `req` sends a REQUEST to the server, checks if the request was loaded (`readyState 4`) and verify if the request was successful (`HTTP status 200`). If these conditions are met, then the program will create a variable with the DATA returned from the request and uses this data to fill the HTML webpage.

Ps: you could also use `req.responseText` to convert the json object directly to a DOMString.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a placeholder for the user data in your HTML:

`<h1 id="name"></h1>`

Then in the javascript of the page you need to make a request to your /getuserdata endpoint and then modify the DOM with the result of the API call:

```
<script>
  fetch('http://example.com/getuserdata')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(user => {
       document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = user.name; 
    });
<script>
```